# Initialization of the structure containing pointer to another structure in C99

Tags: c, struct, initialization, c99

I've some structures definitions below :

```
typedef struct { 
  uint16_t a ;
} my_type1_t ;

typedef struct { 
  uint16_t b ; 
} my_type2_t ; 

typedef struct {
  my_type1_t* a_ptr ;
  my_type2_t* b_ptr ;
} both_t ; 

typedef struct {
  both_t* both_ptr ;
} gathered_t
```

and some instances of the above structures :

```
my_type1_t a = { 
  .a = 0x01U,
} ;

my_type2_t b = { 
  .b = 0xAAU,
} ;
```

I'd like to ask is this possible in C99 standard or higher to do some initialization of the structure as below:

```
gathered_t all = {
  .both_ptr.a_ptr = &a,
  .both_ptr.b_ptr = &b,
};
```

I know that solution of this problem can be defining instance of the both_t structure, however this introduces additional object which consumes memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your structure declares a pointer type you'd have to allocate memory for the object somewhere. But you don't need to have to declare a variable for that, a compound literal would do:

```
gathered_t all = {
  .both_ptr = &(both_t){ 
     .a_ptr = &a,
     .b_ptr = &b,
   }
};
```

The compound literal is allocated according to the scope where this initialization is found; if it is at file scope the allocation would be static, otherwise it would be automatic (on the "stack");

Here, if you don't add any storage specifier to the declaration of `all`, this compound literal then would have the same lifetime as that variable.

Comment: I've checked your solution and it seems to be working, however can you  please tell me where this object was allocated then ? on the stack ?

Comment: I've checked my map file once more time and I saw that this object is basically allocated in the RAM memory but don't have any symbol assigned.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens for the answer, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. You will require memory for the `both_t` anyway. So the solution

```
both_t both = { &a, &b };
gathered_t all = { &both };
```

will use exactly as much memory as you expect.

See other answers to avoid the introduction of a new variable `both`, which show a new feature of C99 indeed.

Comment: yeah, I realized my mistake after typing.

Comment: @BryanOliver Hey Bryan, your code makes sense to me as that's what I read in my book.But can you kindly tell me what those syntax linke `{.both_ptr={.a_ptr=&a,.b_ptr=&b}}` and stuff mean?Why do they append a ".".What am I missing?What I need to study to make sense of it?None of it is mentioned in my C book.

Comment: @BryanOlivier What field names?Can you kindly elaborate?I had read only the syntax you mentioned before you edited your answer.Like `gathered_t all = {{&a,&b}}`.What am I missing?Does C99 introduce a whole new gamut of sytax and rules?

Comment: @BryanOlivier How urgent it is to be familiar with C99?I guess I know only C89 and haven't faced much issues yet.....

Comment: C99 adds convenience features, in this it avoids thinking of names for variables and being able to place them inside the struct that you are actually intending to define. All C89 stuff in this respect keeps working.

Comment: @Sheer Fish I should wake up first. All the `.` are to denote you are defining a field and not referring to a (global) variable.

Comment: @BryanOlivier So what's the difference between your initial code ie `gathered_t all={{&a,&b}}` and  this `gathered_t all={.both_ptr={.a_ptr=&a,.b_ptr=&b}}`? I mean your initial code seems more simple and convenient?What is the benefit of the second code, with "." before variable names and all?

Comment: @BryanOlivier Why use field names in the initialization when we can simply mention the values intended to be stored in those variables?Just as you did in your initial code?Isn't `gathered_t all={{&a,&b}}` convenient?

Comment: @SheerFish In my initial code I was assuming `both_t` was part of `gathered_t` as a single struct, not as a pointer. So it's memory is part of `gathered_t`. `gathered_t` contains however a pointer, so the memory should reside outside the `gathered_t`. This is facilitated by the new C99 syntax.

Comment: @BryanOlivier I am not familiar with C99.How pressing is the need for someone to learn C99 today if he knows only C89?

Comment: @SheerFish it is as pressing as to switch to modern Greek, if you want to buy bread in Greece.

Comment: @Bryan Olivier Thanks Bryan for the answer, however this kind of solution is for me already known.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gathered_t all = {
    .both_ptr = &(both_t){ &a, &b }
};
```

Full example at http://codepad.org/kGxiPPxT

Comment: Thanks a lot Arun this answer seems to be true as well.